# getting an jsp error: org.apache.jasper.jasperException: Unable to complile class for jsp

Tags: jsp

I just start to work with jsp but having some troble with it so far. I am trying to use bean but getting an error and not sure how to fix it.

**I have added the following Jar files:**  servlet.jar and javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar inside /WEB-INFO/lib folder

**Bean Path =** /T_04_JSTL_01_Bean/src/MyPackage/Bean1.java

**Bean Location =** C:\Users\Dave\My_WorkSpace\Eclipse_Workspaces\workspace-jsp\T_04_JSTL_01_Bean\src\MyPackage\Bean1.java

> **JSP File code:**

```
<jsp:useBean id="userBean" class="MyPackage.Bean1" />
```

> **Error:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [52] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\dave\My_WorkSpace\Eclipse_Workspaces\workspace-jsp\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\T_04_JSTL_01_Bean\org\apache\jsp\ex01_005f2_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: The container obviously already has the servlet and jsp jar files, since it must implement all the classes that are in there. You must NOT add those files to your war file.

Comment: I have no idea. I just removed my jsp jar file and it worked!!!